# Extracting subset of lines of a file based on regex for first & last line

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a large text file and I only want to look at some of the lines. The first line I want matches a regex `R`, and when the line matches the regex `S`, I don't care about that line, or any following lines. Lines in the middle will not match `R`. Is there a way to do this on the command line in a bash command so I can pipe the output somewhere after?

Comment: Please give input and output examples, and what means a line in the middle? Not the first and not the last line?

Comment: For GNU `sed '/R/,/S/!d;/S/Q' large.text.file`

Comment: More portable `sed --posix -n '/R/{:1;p;n;/S/!b1;};/S/q'`

Comment: Your POSIX one is not POSIX (`;` is a valid character in the name of a label, you need `;` before `}` (and can't have anything after)

Comment: @chaos, though an example might help, the question is clearly specified without any ambiguity (the only possible one being whether a line may match both R and S) which is rare enough here to be praised. It certainly doesn't warrant closing as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/R/,$!d; /S/q; p'
```

Example:

```
$ seq 20 | sed -n '/6/,$!d; /1/q; p'
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk

```
awk 'x&&/S/{exit};x+=/R/' file
```

Example

```
seq 20 | awk 'x&&/1/{exit};x+=/6/'
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: It could be optimised by not looking for subsequent `R`s like `awk '/R/,0{if (/S/) exit; print}'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Cool,don't edit my answer to add unnecessary semi colons please :)

Comment: the semi-colon is required by POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No they aren't ? Atleast not when using the `--posix` or `--compat` argument ? Also for your optimisation, i doubt that would make even a seconds difference on a terabyte file.

Comment: Actually, I even once [filed a request to the Austin group](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226) so that restriction be relaxed as I couldn't find any implementation that enforced it but it was rejected by the maintainer of GNU awk. (please also note that my comments are never intended as being confrontational, only at adding information).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If you had commented that to be posix compliant you needed a `;` then i would have just added it. I just think its a bit rude to change peoples answer without asking, for something that has not been stated as a requirement by OP. Also I knew that `/1/;{blah}` was disallowed by posix, but are you sure that `{blah}/1/` is? If you are i will add the colons to the answer.

Comment: `/1/;{blah}` is meant to be allowed by POSIX (and the original `awk` (not `awk 'x+=/R/'` though), though POSIX `awk` is not based on that one but on `nawk`). It's `{blah}/1/` that's not. See [the grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16). I take note not to edit your answers in the future.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can't find it, but i'll just believe you, I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: As for the optimisation gain, that very much depends on the cost of your R regexp. Compare for instance `seq 1111111111110000 1111111111119999 | mawk '/(1+1+)+2/,0{if (/9999/) exit; print}'` with `seq 1111111111110000 1111111111119999 | mawk 'x&&/9999/{exit};x+=/(1+1+)+2/'`. I get 3 seconds difference, though the input is only a few kilo-bytes, not tera-bytes.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment. You're right that `/1/;{blah}` was not allowed by POSIX and that was one of the points I raised in [my request to the austin group](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226). [As Don Cragun notes there](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2228), that was not intentional and will be fixed (see the [grammar change](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2227)) so that now you can have any sequence of pattern-less or action-less or pattern-action items provided they are separated by ; or newline.

Answer (score 2):

with perl:

```
# perl -ne 'print if ( /R/ .. /S/ ); last if /S/'
```

It does print the S-Matching regexp, tho'

Answer (score -1):

I have written a programme to solve this [fromto](https://github.com/rory/fromto-printer-py)

You can  use it like this:

```
cat file | fromto -f R -T S
```

Where `R` is the regex you want to grab *from*, and `S` is the regex you want to grab *to*. It will print out all lines between those two. `-f` means "include the 'from' line", `-F` would mean "don't include the 'from' line". Likewise with `-t`/`-T`. The question was to exclude the 'to' line, hence `-T` is the argument for that requirement. If you used `-t` it would print the 'to' line (but not lines afterwards)

Comment: Plese explain about your application.

Comment: I have expanded this to include details.